Log In Code Does Not Work but Sign Up Does
I'm trying to make a signup/login system using Firebase.
The signup page works, when I click the sign up button it sends me to the homepage (RAB.html). But when I go to the log in page and click the log in button, it errors:

This page isn't working, HTTP ERROR 405

What seems to be the problem?
this is my code:
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/11.1.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/11.1.0/firebase-analytics.js";
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/11.1.0/firebase-auth.js"
import {getFirestore, setDoc, doc} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/11.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBhDkEUta73LDAm-Zah0vU-uGpVRTN6PaA",
  authDomain: "rabp-6ae41.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "rabp-6ae41",
  storageBucket: "rabp-6ae41.firebasestorage.app",
  messagingSenderId: "124825740643",
  appId: "1:124825740643:web:1b888d74e3adfd15575f56",
  measurementId: "G-EYVYX974MD"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

function showMessage(message, divId) {
  var messageDiv=document.getElementById(divId);
  messageDiv.style.display="block";
  messageDiv.innerHTML=message;
  messageDiv.style.opacity=1;
  setTimeout(function(){
    messageDiv.style.opacity=0;
  },5000);
}

const signUp=document.getElementById('submitSignUp');
signUp.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
  const email=document.getElementById('rEmail').value;
  const password=document.getElementById('rPassword').value;
  const firstName=document.getElementById('fName').value;
  const lastName=document.getElementById('lName').value;
  const address=document.getElementById('rAddress').value;
  const number=document.getElementById('rNumber').value;

  const auth=getAuth();
  const db=getFirestore();

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential)=>{
    const user=userCredential.user;
    const userData= {
      email: email, 
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      address: address,
      number: number
    };
    showMessage('Account Created Successfully', 'signUpMessage');
    const docRef=doc(db, "users", user.uid);
    setDoc(docRef,userData)
    .then(()=>{
      window.location.href='RAB.html';
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.error("error writing document", error);

    });
  })
  .catch((error)=> {
    const errorCode=error.code;
    if(errorCode=='auth/email-already-in-use'){
      showMessage('Email Address Already Exists !!!', 'signUpMessage')
    } else {
      showMessage('unable to create User', 'signUpMessage');
    }
  })
})

const signIn = document.getElementById('submitSignIn');
signIn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{                                                                                                                 
  event.preventDefault();
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  
  const auth = getAuth();

  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential)=>{
    showMessage('login is successful', 'signInMessage');
    const user=userCredential.user;
    localStorage.setItem('loggedInUserId', user.uid); 
    window.location.href='RAB.html';
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    const errorCode=error.code;
    if(errorCode ==='auth/invalid-credential'){
      showMessage('Incorrect Email or Password', 'signInMessage');
    } else {
      showMessage('Account does not Exist', 'signInMessage')
    }
  })
})



I don't think that error comes from the Firebase SDK. If you set a breakpoint on each line of code that you shared, and then step through your code line-by-line in the debugger, which exact lines raises the error?

Thank you for the reply. I noticed that when I go to the html of the login page, and remove the , it doesn't send me to an error page anymore. But then, the button doesn't work.
